# What are the gaseous outputs of electrolysis of Water along with NaOH or KOH?

Tags: electrolysis, hydrolysis

Theoretically electrolysis of water yields Hydrogen and Oxygen in gaseous form.
But to enhance conductivity we have to add an electrolyte like $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{KOH}$.

Does this produce any other gases along with Oxygen? Does $\ce{Na+}$ or $\ce{OH^-}$ ions also come out as some form of gas? Or practically speaking can people breathe the oxygen which comes out of electrolysis?

**What are the gaseous outputs of electrolysis of Water along with $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\ce{KOH}$?**

Comment: Per your third question: it's done that way in submarines and [on the ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water#Applications). Also, you might want to break-up this question into more concise ones. There is a chance this might be close for lacking focus.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt all I want to know if can we breathe electrolysis generated oxygen safely. I'm concerned about electrolyte generating toxic gases. You are welcome to edit. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ToddMinehardt what electrolyte do they use in Submarine

Comment: @NilayGhosh Thank you so much. Regarding the oxygen shortage in India, can people use electrolysis on distilled water to create breathable Oxygen??